# Using jQuery plugin LavaLamp

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm having problems using the jQuery plugin [LavaLamp](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/);

I followed [this](http://www.dreamweavertutorial.co.uk/dreamweaver/articles/jquery-lavalamp-menu.htm) tutorial but nothing works.

Has anyone used this plugin and could tell me what I'm doing wrong [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/JQvdn/3/) site?

Green menu item should follow the mouse pointer.
As a test I'm just putting an edge to move the mouse pointer;

How can I run this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you wrote is not working and it seems the Javascript of the lavellamp is not loaded correctly, however, I change your example as [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/EYALN/).

Comment: why the yellow box is over the menu?
How can I let you down?

Comment: because you specified the CSS of ul#header-menu li.back